# iPhone 4s can deleted text in spotlight be retrieved

Tags: ios

How do I retrieve erased text messages on iPhone 4s?
When I do a spotlight search part of the message is displayed so I asume the whole message is There, I just don't know how to extract the file.

Answer (score 1):

When you delete a message from, for example the messages app, they will be deleted from you iDevice. A way to retrieve the message is restoring from a backup.

Normally the message shouldn't be shown in spotlight when it is deleted, so I unfortunately do not have an answer for that.